# Multiple Azure Cloud Services in One Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2012

I have 3 web projects running on Azure, currently all sites inside one instance, great for reducing cost but not so great when one of the web projects has peaks in demand which slow the other services down / bring it to a halt.

2 of the sites sit on the same domain (one with different port) and one on a subdomain. The great thing about sites is that you can use host names to differentiate between sites running on the same port. If the subdomain site were referenced as a web role it would require different ports to the other two web roles - not what I'm after at all!

The problem is that although I could use two cloud services you cannot debug them simultaneously inside a solution. Placing them inside two solutions eases the problem but they share a class library which changes often, having this inside a separate solution to the web roles makes it very tricky to debug in my experience.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the real question here?

First, I don't see an issue with having all sites in a single WebRole. When one gets peak - just scale out. Yes, you will be scaling all of the sites, but this is only an advantage. The Windows Azure Load Balancer uses RoundRobin algorithm, which guarantees all the requests are send evenly across all instances. I will say it again - when you see peaks, just scale out, nothing to worry about. After all, this is what Azure stands there for. For costs it doesn't really matter, because you will be scaling anyway. Whether a single site per web role, or 10 sites per web role, the scale is scale and takes the same money.

As for the other concern. I've been dealing a lot with a multi project solutions. And I've never seen issues with a common library used by multiple projects. Especially when everything is under (source) control. Visual Studio has the neat feature of "Add Existing Project" (when you right click on the solution):

[image: Add Existing Project]

So, you common class library is just a single project used in many solutions and edited on a single place of the file system.

As bottom line, I will say again - if the only bother you have is that when you scale out the site under peak, you will also scale the other sites, just don't! And if you don't want to scale under heavy peak, and let the site down - just don't bother using Azure.

Comment: I do scale out, so no this currently isn't an issue. I had no idea that adding an existing project simply referenced it so thanks for that! I suppose my question is: is it worth separating a website from an API by splitting them into different cloud services?

Comment: The main motivation for separation would be to allow different update cycles and different scaling patterns so this is what you will need to weigh against what to you is adding complexity around debug because of the often changing shared assembly. maybe you need to look at how to manage that if separation is desirable?

Comment: Thanks Yossi. At the end of the day the API will rarely ever change at the same time as the other two roles and yes, the scaling patterns will be different so you've answered my question, thanks again!

Comment: @YossiDahan Just to clarify a bit; what do you mean by update cycle and scaling patterns? In the answer above we see that scaling doesn't matter weather you have all sites in one WebRole, or if you have a single site per WebRole. And for update cycle  are you talking about updating parts of your application at different times and publishing those parts to production? I guess I wasn't aware that you could do this. Seems like we have to publish all the services to production if we make a change to just one. I could just be way off on that so please correct me if I am wrong.